# SSIS Job looping over csv files

Tags: ssis, jobs

How can I loop through multiple files in a data flow task .

Right now it raeds just one file , what to do if I need to read multiple files in a data flow task

Comment: For the referenced dupe, change the file extension from txt to csv

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you could do (like moving/deleting the files after reading), but I will keep it just at reading the files.

1. Create a `for each loop` in your control flow. (this has to be done in the control flow.)
2. double click on the `for each loop`, and go to the `collection` tab.
3. Select `for each file enumerator` (in the drop-down)
4. Under enumerator configuration, select the right folder and write `*.csv` under Files. Under Retrieve file name, select `fully qualified`
5. Go to the `variable mapping` tab. Insert the variable `CurrentFile` with an Index of 0 (should be default)
6. Close the for each editor window. Add your dataflow in the for each loop container.
7. Open the dataflow and parametrize your connection manager. Use the variable `CurrentFile`.
8. You're ready to go

Some good material (with extras):

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS

Comment: Hi Den , Thanks. I have done till step 6 but when I try to parameterize my connection manager , it throws an error .The acquire connection method calls to the connection manager fails .

Comment: Hi Tab, can you help please

Comment: Anyone help please